# Class prefix in intentdefinition generated code

Tags: xcode, sirikit, widgetkit

When adding an `.intentdefinition` file to Xcode (for my widget configuration) the classes it generates are prefixed with (in my case) HixField which is my company name.

- Where is this coming from? I did not enter this somewhere?
- I don't like this, can this prefix be safely removed?
- Why would this prefix be added? What is the reason for it?

My findings:

- if you select the file you can indeed set a custom class in the property inspector. But I am hesitant as there might be a reason for the prefix...
- if you open the .intentdefinition file I find this entry

```
<key>INIntentClassPrefix</key>
<string>HixField</string>
```

changing this to an empty string has no effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the Class Prefix setting on your Xcode project. Select your Xcode project and open the file inspector to change it.

[image: Class Prefix setting in Xcode]